# 2D Nearest Neighbor Interpolation in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, nearest-neighbor

Suppose that we have the following look up table

```
        | 1.23    2.63    4.74    6.43    5.64
 -------|--------------------------------------
 -------|--------------------------------------
 2.56   |  0       0      1        0       1
 4.79   |  0       1      1        1       0
 6.21   |  1       0      0        0       0
```

This table contains a labeling matrix (having only `0` and `1`s), `x` values and `y` values. How one can have **nearest-neighbor interpolation** for this look up table?

**Example:**

```
Input: (5.1, 4.9)
Output: 1

Input: (3.54, 6.9)
Output: 0
```

Comment: Why is it tagged with scipy and numpy? Does the answer have to use those libs? Also: what did you try?

Comment: @FilipMalczak I generally wanted to see if there are special functions in these libraries. I was thinking of implementing it with `scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator`. However, I was wondering how good and efficient it is for my problem.

Comment: So you do know how to implement it, but you're wondering if it is already implemented? If it so, then I think that this question - however interesting - is out of scope of SO. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ; I think that this question is too close to point 4 from first of those links. I'm not flagging it though - it may get constructive answers that will be useful for some people.

Comment: @A.M. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30057858/832621) might give you some insight

Comment: @SaulloCastro Thanks Saullo :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Look up table

If you have the complete table you don't need interpolation, you just need to look up the index of the nearest (x, y) value and use it on the table

```
In [1]: import numpy
   ...: x = numpy.array([1.23, 2.63, 4.74, 6.43, 5.64])
   ...: y = numpy.array([2.56, 4.79, 6.21])
   ...: data = numpy.array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
   ...:                     [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
   ...:                     [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
   ...: 
   ...: def lookupNearest(x0, y0):
   ...:     xi = numpy.abs(x-x0).argmin()
   ...:     yi = numpy.abs(y-y0).argmin()
   ...:     return data[yi,xi]

In [2]: lookupNearest(5.1, 4.9)
Out[2]: 1

In [3]: lookupNearest(3.54, 6.9)
Out[3]: 0
```

### Nearest-neighbor interpolation

`scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator` will be really useful if your data is composed by scattered points

For example, for data like:

[image]
with red = 1, blue =0

```
In [4]: points = numpy.array([[1.1, 2.5], 
   ...:                       [1.5, 5.2], 
   ...:                       [3.1, 3.0], 
   ...:                       [2.0, 6.0], 
   ...:                       [2.8, 4.7]])
   ...: values = numpy.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])

In [5]: from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator
   ...: myInterpolator = NearestNDInterpolator(points, values)

In [6]: myInterpolator(1.7,4.5)
Out[6]: 1

In [7]: myInterpolator(2.5,4.0)
Out[7]: 0
```

Comment: First part of the answer is wrong. Consider points: A=(0, 0), B=(1, 100), C=(2, 2). Your code would state that nearest neighbour of A is B, even though it's not true. Try something like `min(data, key=lambda point: (point.x-your_point.x)**2 + (point.y-your_point.y)**2)` (it's a general idea, I know that you won't be able to get coordinates as properties). No downvote, because second, scipy/numpy related part seems to be more important.

Comment: @FilipMalczak The first part of my answer will work if the data is arranged in a rectangular grid (a complete table)

Comment: Fair enough, I've generalized it to example from second part of the post.