# python scipy 3D interpolation / look up table

Tags: python, 3d, scipy, interpolation, lookup-tables

I have data produced from Comsol which I would like to use as a look up table in a Python / Scipy program I am building. The output from comsol looks like B(ri,thick,L) and will contain approximately 20,000 entries. An example of the output is shown below for a reduced 3x3x3 version.

While I have found many good solutions for 3D interpolation using e.g. regulargridinterpolator (first link below), I am still looking for a solution using the lookup table style. The second link below seems close, however I am unsure how the method interpolates over all three dimensions.

I am having a hard time believing that a lookup table requires such an elaborate implementation, so any suggestions are most appreciated!

[COMSOL data example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wM5lE.jpg)

[interpolate 3D volume with numpy and or scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21836067/interpolate-3d-volume-with-numpy-and-or-scipy)

[Interpolating data from a look up table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29974122/interpolating-data-from-a-look-up-table)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out and wanted to pass on my solution to the next person. I found that merely averaging the two closest points found via a cKDtree yielded errors as large as 10%.

Instead, I used the cKDtree to find the appropriate entry in the scattered look up table / data file and assign it to the correct entry of a 3D numpy array (You can save this numpy array to file if you like). Then I use rectangulargridinterpolator on this array. Errors were on the order of 0.5 percent which was an order of magnitude better than the cKDtree.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
from scipy.interpolate import RegularGridInterpolator

l_data = np.linspace(.125,0.5,16)# np.linspace(0.01,0.1,10) #Range for "short L"
ri_data = np.linspace(0.005,0.075,29)
thick_data = np.linspace(0.0025,0.1225,25)
#xyz data with known bounds above
F = np.zeros((np.size(l_data),np.size(ri_data),np.size(thick_data)))


LUT = np.genfromtxt('a_data_file.csv', delimiter = ',')
F_val = LUT[:, 3]
tree_small_l = cKDTree(LUT[:, :3]) #xyz coords

for ri_iter in np.arange(np.size(ri_data)):
    for thick_iter in np.arange(np.size(thick_data)):
        for l_iter in np.arange(np.size(l_data)):    
            dist,ind = tree_small_l.query(((l_data[l_iter],ri_data[ri_iter],thick_data[thick_iter])))
            F[l_iter,ri_iter,thick_iter] = F_val[ind].T 

interp_F_func = RegularGridInterpolator((l_data, ri_data, thick_data), F)
```